# How to use exponent "E" with superscript numbers?

Tags: siunitx, superscripts

Using `siunitx` i would like to change the exponent marker to be `E` but maintain the exponent number in superscript

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    output-exponent-marker={\,\mathrm{E}},
}
\begin{document}
    \num{1e2} % Outputs 1E2 instead of 1E^2
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it common notation?

Comment: I was advised by my teacher to use this notation as it would be more adequate than just using as it was previously, and sincerely i have been growing found of if, is more readable than not using superscript and has less characters than `10^x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `output-exponent-marker`, you could keep the "1 x 10²" form, but replace the product symbol and the base of the exponent with a space and an "E" using `exponent-product` and `exponent-base`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    exponent-product={\,},
    exponent-base={\mathrm{E}},
}
\begin{document}
    \num{1e2}
\end{document}
```